# How can I use swiffy swf javascript library with JsObject Interrop in Dart to run a SWF animation?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to use Javascript interrop for the use of swiffy swf converter.

In Javascript, when you convert a swf animation on swiffy website you receive a JSon script that represent your animation and you should use two methods to run it in javascript :

```javascript
    var DOMElement = document. getElementById("#Html5logo")
    var JSonString = {/*JSon swiffy annimation*/}

    Swiffy.Stage(DOMElement,JSonString)
    Swiffy.Start();
```

I have trying to integrate this in a Dart polymer-element as describe in my example :

```dart
  //Grab the DOMElement with querySelector('#ID') or $['ID']
  Element html5DivContainer = $['html5logo'];

  //Put JSon Swiffy Logo into a MAP
  Map html5logoJSon = {/*Valid JSonObject*/}

  //Load swiffy Javascript library by using context JsObject Interrop from Dart
  JsObject swiffy = context['swiffy'];

  //This test is ok in my case.
  if(swiffy.hasProperty('Stage')){
    print('Swiffy well loaded and Stage methods is found.');
  }

  //TRY 01 : Try to load Stage Methods by parsing my DOMElement and my jsify Swiffy JSon Object.
  //
  // Result as an Exception :
  //    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Xe'
  //    CtrlHeader.CtrlHeader.created (http://127.0.0.1:3030/MySwiffyExample/web/ctrlheader.dart:19:24)
  swiffy.callMethod('Stage', [html5DivContainer,new JsObject.jsify(html5logoJSon)]);

  //TRY 02 : Try to load Stage Methods by parsing my jsify DOMElement and my jsify Swiffy JSon Object.
  //
  // Result as an Exception :
  //    Exception: Illegal argument(s): object must be a Map or Iterable
  //    CtrlHeader.CtrlHeader.created (http://127.0.0.1:3030/MySwiffyExample/web/ctrlheader.dart:33:39)
  swiffy.callMethod('Stage', [new JsObject.jsify(html5DivContainer),new JsObject.jsify(html5logoJSon)]);

  //Any idea??
```

complete test case :
http://pastebin.com/XGhL9ejf

I think i can't send DomElement as a args. You can found here the swiffy 5.4 JS Script that I use for interrop in Dart :

```
  http://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.4/runtime.js
```

Thanks you !

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't have experience with StageXL but maybe it is a better solution than Swiffy: http://www.stagexl.org/

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it but I just want to understand why JsObject interrop for dart is not working for this example. And to be more complete, i would like to know why parsing DomElement not working in this case. is this a problem from swiffy? Or from my code?

Answer (score 0):

The try 01 should have worked :

```dart
swiffy.callMethod('Stage',[html5DivContainer,new JsObject.jsify(html5logoJSon)]);
```

Comment: No, it's not working. I have checked again for all my script and dependence. It's working when i wrote in javascript but not working in dart. I have try also with a blank project. Same error.

Comment: Have you try without polymer ?